# memory access out of bounds – but why?

Tags: webassembly, assemblyscript

I'm sharing a piece of memory between js and wasm, using 'imported' memory. in my assemblyscript code I'm not even accessing the preallocated memory and still get a `RuntimeError: memory access out of bounds`. I would like to understand why.

js:

```
const [width, height] = [100, 100];
const arraySize = width * height;
const pageSize = 64 * 1024;
const nPages = Math.ceil(arraySize / pageSize);
const memory = new WebAssembly.Memory({ 
  initial: nPages 
});
WebAssembly
  .instantiateStreaming(fetch('/build/optimized.wasm'), {
    env: {
      memory,
      abort: (_msg, _file, line, column) => {
        console.error(`Abort at ${line}:${column}`)
      },
    }
  })
  .then(({instance}) => {
    const bytes = new Uint8ClampedArray(memory.buffer);
    
    // A
    for (let i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
      bytes[i] = 1;
    }

    instance.exports.asdf(width, height);
  });
```

assemblyscript:

```
export function asdf(width: i32, height: i32): void {
  // B
  const arr = new Uint8Array(width * height);
}
```

when I remove either `A` or `B` it works.

---

edit:

weird: setting `const [width, height] = [39, 39];` also produces no error.

---

edit 2:

I'm using imported memory because all the examples I found do that. should I perhaps be creating arrays, etc. the way they show here? https://www.assemblyscript.org/loader.html#creating-arrays

Comment: Did you use `--importMemory` flag for `asc`?

Comment: yes, I did do that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any errors. See [playground](https://www.assemblyscript.org/editor.html#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)

Also this keep in mind when you allocate memory in AssemblyScript you may overwrite initialized memory before on the host side according your example.